# Can A .swf loaded with SWFLoader propagate events to the parent application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, events, event-handling

I am building a compartmentalized Flex application which uses `<SWFLoader >` to load additional Flex applications inside it.  I am currently planning on using the LocalConnection class to have these two applications talk to each other, but I'm wondering if there's any kind of event driven way to have actions in the internal application propagate to the parent application, and/or any way for the parent application to trigger events in the internal application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389973/using-a-button-within-flash-movie-in-flex-flash-builder/3393482#3393482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it can but be careful what types you pass across the bridge if you are loading with loadForCompatability=true.   Have a look at this document [LoaderInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) paying particular attention to sharedEvents.  It basically allows you to raise events from the subApplication to the parent and vice versa.  For more complex scenarios, using AIR have a look at the child/parent Sandbox bridges.